# After an animation (css3), the image doesn't disappear totaly

Tags: css

I have an image on my web page and when I hover it, I want to hide it and display a background with a text.

I have something like :

```
<div class="col-md-15 col-lg-15 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 gridImage">
        <img src="images/bonheur.jpg" class="img-responsive gridImage" id="">
</div>
```

I tried with JQuery but I didn't success. (`.hover`)

I'm trying with css3 but my problem is : when the animation is over, the image appears again.

My code is :

```
.gridImage>img:hover
{
    animation : test 1s infinite;
}



@keyframes test {
    0% {opacity : 0.9}
    20% {opacity : 0.8}
    40% {opacity : 0.6}
    50% {opacity : 0.5}
    60% {opacity:0.4}
    80% {opacity : 0.2}
    90% {opacity : 0}
    100% {opacity : 0}
}
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using animate if you want to completely hide the image on hover. Use opacity: 0 with transition and you will get  clean effect.

I have absolutly placed a text in the middle which has been hidden on normal condition with the help of z-index

Here goes the code.

```css
.gridImage>img:hover
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 2s all ease;
}
.gridImage{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500p; 
}
.gridImage img{
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2
}
.gridImage:hover{
  background: #333;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}
.gridImage h1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-15 col-lg-15 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 gridImage">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" class="img-responsive gridImage" id="">
  <h1>
        This is an image
        </h1>
</div>
```

I hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just turn opacity to 0 when mouse hover by animation you should put forwards property in your animation to avoid returning to opacity 1 and set animation-iteration-count to 1 instead of infinite such `animation : test 1s forwards 1 ;` 
And this is the code :

```css
.gridImage {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}

.gridImage > img:hover {
    animation : test 1s forwards 1 ;
    z-index:9999
}

.gridImage > H1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:180px;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition-delay:0s;
}

.gridImage:hover H1 {
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay:1s
}

@keyframes test {
    0% {opacity : 0.9}
    20% {opacity : 0.8}
    40% {opacity : 0.6}
    50% {opacity : 0.5}
    60% {opacity:0.4}
    80% {opacity : 0.2}
    90% {opacity : 0}
    100% {opacity : 0}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-15 col-lg-15 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 gridImage">
        <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" class="img-responsive gridImage" id="">
  <H1>This is test</H1>
</div>
```

hope this will help.